# Java StringTokenizer respects exactly five whitespace characters and nothing else

Tags: java, guava

What does the following mean:

> ... and StringTokenizer respects exactly five whitespace
>   characters and nothing else.

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably it means that `StringTokenizer` will break on `\n`, `\r`, space, TAB, and formfeed, by default. From the source for the simplest constructor:

```
this(str, " \t\n\r\f", false);
```

You see the five whitespace characters listed there. This is not really a big deal, though, because you can specify your own delimiters using one of the other constructors. `StringTokenizer` has plenty of other problems; the default set of whitespace characters is the least of its worries.

Comment: But you can specify your [own delimiters](http://bit.ly/Lh9Tiu) for `StringTokenizer`

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill Yes for a moment i thought so too, this is misleading us hehe :)

Comment: Yeah, I could see the statement being a bit misleading. That said, it _is_ a bit weird for `StringTokenizer` to have this basically arbitrary set of characters that it chooses to break on by default if you don't specify something else.

Comment: What StringTokenizer gives you by default is just strange. And in case you really want *all whitespace characters* and you don't know them all (do you?), something like `Splitter.on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE)` comes in handy.

Comment: @maaartinus -- Remember that `StringTokenizer` existed in JDK 1.0. All of the oldest Java classes were written by folks who had never written in Java before (of course.) This list of whitespace character is the list of US-ASCII whitespace characters, and I am sure it made a lot of sense at the time: writing ASCII-only code was pretty much standard procedure in those days. It was probably taken from code in some other language, C perhaps.

Comment: Agreed. I don't blame Java designers for what they did back in the days when coal was young. I just disagree with you w.r.t. the argument being "specious". For me `StringTokenizer` is dead since years and Guava is the way to go.

Comment: @maaartinus -- agreed, that does sound a little snotty. Emended.

Comment: And `\v` isn't considered?

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing this refers to the default set of delimiters for a `StringTokenizer`, which are space, `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and `\f`.

Answer (score 4):

I think the larger point being made here is that of unexpected behavior in the Java APIs on some of these String issues, especially regarding whitespace and splitting. The default `StringTokenizer` uses whitespace as a delimiter, but under a very unique definition of whitespace (e.g., every other definition in the Java APIs seems to include line tabulation, whereas the default `StringTokenizer` does not. One could reasonably be confused as to why the string being passed in from a user genuinely has whitespace, but is not being split, before finally realizing  that, oops, it's a non-breaking space, widely used all over the web. Yes, if you inspect the request closely, you'll find this out, and if you dig into the Javadoc, you'll see that this is the default behavior, and yes, you can just specify a different set of characters when you construct your `StringTokenizer`, but that doesn't make it less annoying.

But I think the Guava argument expands even more widely than unexpected behavior in this one case. The Java API in general is abysmally inconsistent in how it defines whitespace, which is why they have created `CharMatcher.WHITESPACE`. Check out all the different definitions [here](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pd8dAQyHbdewRsnE5x5GzKQ), compiled by Guava author Kevin Bourrillion

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the "five whitespace characters" to which they refer are: space, \t, \r, \n, and \f.